# ng-class to select button based on condition in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code where I am displaying buttons based on array values. I want to select button based on a condition which checks if it matches with another array values. I have added an ng-class to check i in array1 loop matches listApi but couldn't come up with correct logic and get it tow work. Need help please

```html
<label ng-repeat="i inn array1 track by $index">
    <label class="btn-primary" ng-click="array1Selection()">
        <span ng-class="{'btn-primary': i.name === listApi[0].name}"></span>
        {{i.name}}
    </label>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `span` tag is empty and I think you should put `{{i.name}}` inside that. also you should not add class `'btn ...'` to your label. Hope this code helps you.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "abc"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "xyz"
  }];

  $scope.listApi = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "xyz"
  }];

  $scope.existInList = function(itm) {
    let x = $scope.listApi.findIndex(it => {
      return it.name == itm.name
    });
    return x == -1 ? false : true;
  }

});
```

```css
.exists {
  color: green
}

.noexists {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h2>Add class to existing items and others</h2>
  <label ng-repeat="i in array1">
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label>
      <div class="itemcontent">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array1Select" />
        <span ng-class="{true: 'exists', false: 'noexists'}[existInList(i) === true]">
                {{i.name}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  </label>

  <h2>Show only if exists in list</h2>
  <label ng-repeat="i in array1">
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label  ng-if="existInList(i)">
      <div class="itemcontent">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array1Select" />
        <span>
                {{i.name}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
  </label>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure JS' `find` will work inline in `Angular` but is so...

```html
<label ng-repeat="i inn array1 track by $index">
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" ng-click="array1Selection()">
      <div class="itemcontent">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array1Select" />
        <span nng-class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary: listApi.find(a => a.name === i.name)"></span>
        {{i.name}}
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: How to make it enabled by default. do you think above ng-class is correct. I meant btn btn-w-m btn-primary:

Comment: Depends what you want. btn-primary just makes a blue button in default Bootstrap. If the other buttons are btn-default that should be ok.

Comment: above solution didnot work. Even with a hard coded value instead of listApi compare

Comment: what do you think is wrong with my html. i had my ng-class to be like this <span nng-class="{'btn btn-w-m btn-primary': i.name === 'abc'}">

Comment: I use [ngClass] in my projects. So <span [ngClass]="btn btn-w-m btn-primary: listApi.find(a => a.name === i.name)"></span>

Comment: Give it a try. Let's figure it out

Comment: OK. Let's hope an Angular guru jumps in

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.array1 = [{ id: 1, name: "abc" }, { id: 1, name: "xyz"
  }];

  $scope.listApi = [{ id: 2, name: "xyz" }];

  $scope.foundInApiList = function(name) {
  
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.listApi.length; i++)
      if($scope.listApi[i].name == name)
        return true;
        
    return false;
  }

});
```

```css
.exists {
  color: green
}

.noexists {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <label ng-repeat="i in array1 track by $index">
  <div data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" ng-click="array1Selection()">
      <div class="itemcontent">
        <input type="checkbox" name="array1Select" />
        <span class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" ng-class="{true: 'exists', false: 'noexists'}[foundInApiList(i.name)]">{{i.name}}</span>        
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</label>

</body>

</html>
```